# illegal start of type Stack myStack= new Stack()

Tags: java, compiler-errors, stack

On my PC (Last JDK and compiler version) my program works like a charm. But on my professor's computer she says she is getting two errors

1)  `illegal start of type Stack myStack= new Stack()`

2) `illegal start of type Stack myStack = new Stack();`

I am 100% sure this is due to an outdated compiler because this did happened before and I had to "generalize" things to fix.
I honestly do not know how to fix this, and I am kind of intermediate in Java.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: what is the jre version on your Prof.'s computer?

Comment: I do apologize guys. I included the code.

Comment: If the prof has Java 6 or lower then the diamond operator on `new Stack<>();` won't work. Not sure what the error message in that case would be though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *guess* that the java version on your professor's computer is `<1.7`. You have used diamond operator in your codes. The diamond operator is only supported by java version `>=1.7`.  And if you compile it with i.e. `java 1.6`, you got exact that error message.

What you can do:

- try to get to know the java version on your prof.'s computer
- if it is <= 1.6, you change your codes:

  ```
  Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<>();
  ```

  into

  ```
  Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();
  ```

Comment: @Pshemo I am always confused by the indentation with bullet.. I just know the code blocks have to be double indented in bullets, but once I have other text (like "into" above), I don't know how to indent... thank you for explaining it to me.